# Gatling - Scala : How to repeat a request until a certain response variable exists in the API response?

Tags: scala, for-loop, while-loop, gatling, scala-gatling

Gatling - Scala : How to repeat a request until a certain response variable exists in the API response?

This is the request to find the response time of a cursor pagination API

```
.exec(http("APITests:Cursor Pagination")
  .get("/testapi")
  .queryParam("sortField", "ID")
  .queryParam("limit", limitCount)
  .queryParam("cursor", "#{CursorID}")
  .check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor")).exists
 .check(status.is(200))
)
```

I have to repeat the request execution until **.check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor")).exists = False**

Please provide suggestions and help

I tried below ending with error:

```
 doWhile(session => session(".check(jsonPath(\"$.nextCursor\").exists").as[Boolean]) {
    exec(http("APITests:Cursor Pagination")
      .get("/testapi")
      .queryParam("sortField", "ID")
      .queryParam("limit", limitCount)
      .queryParam("cursor", "#{CursorID}")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor").exists
    ))
  }
```

But I end up with error :
**jsonPath($.nextCursor).find.exists, found nothing**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contains`, but you have to save `nextCursor` into `Session`

```scala
    doWhile(session => !session.contains("nextCursor")) {
      exec(http("...")
        .get("/")
        .check(jsonPath("$.nextCursor").saveAs("nextCursor"))
      )
    }
```